# Angular 2+ - Parse json data and output only single specific data

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have this code which parses JSON and list data into the table using ngFor.

The result will be like.

[image: result]

Yes, listing data into the table is working fine.

But how can I implement it to output single data of specific ID?

For example - I want the name of id=3 the output should be "Edward".

I can't figure out how to do this. Can someone help me or guide me?

Thanks.

**app-components.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    private data;

    constructor(private http:Http){
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getData();
    }

    getData(){
        this.http.get('/localhost/data.json')
                .subscribe(res => this.data = res.json());
    }

}
```

**app-component.html**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let info of data">
        <td>{{info.id}}</td>
        <td>{{info.name}}</td>
        <td>{{info.amount}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**data.json**

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"1",
      "name":"John",
      "amount":"112"
   },  
   {  
      "id":"2",
      "name":"Maria",
      "amount":"44"
   },  
   {  
      "id":"3",
      "name":"Edward",
      "amount":"40"
   }
]
```

Please tell me that am I providing sufficient information or not.

Comment: So instead of the list you want to have an input or dropdown when selected, prints out the information for that id to another div for example?

Comment: I want to just display data of specific ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `<ng-container>` for the same, this have to use because you cannot apply two directives on a single element like we are using `*ngIf` and `*ngFor`.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let info of data">
    <tr *ngIf='info.id == 3'>
        <td>{{info.id}}</td>
        <td>{{info.name}}</td>
        <td>{{info.amount}}</td>
    </tr>
    </ng-container>
</table >
```

## [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jo3sxf?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks! Can this be used in the back-end like storing just the name of id=3 into variable x?

Comment: yes you can, you need to assign value having `id==3` into your container

Comment: Sorry, I mean assigning the value of 'name' of id=3 into some variable. But don't display it.

Comment: yes, you can !! But didn't get your point what you want to do.
either Update your question or ask new one

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding an `*ngIf` directive , why don't you create a component separately to output only one table row ?

For example : 
table.component.html will have :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{info.id}}</td>
        <td>{{info.name}}</td>
        <td>{{info.amount}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and `table.component.ts` will have :

`@Input() info : any;`

Now you can loop over the `<app-table [info]='info'></app-table>` inside `app-component.html` also , you can just pass `<app-table [info]='info[3]'></app-table>` .